# robot class mouseWheel not working

Tags: java, scroll, mouseevent, awtrobot

I have been working with simulating mouse events with the Robot class for a while, and all was well, until I tried to scroll using the mouseWheel function. I just have this simple line:

```
  Robot robot = new Robot();
  robot.mouseWheel(-100);
```

I have been trying variations of this for a long time, and the program runs, does nothing, then terminates normally. Can someone shed light on why this is?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be very useful to have some of your other code, for example, the code that is supposed to be executed when the mouse wheel is spun.

Comment: What are you testing it on? Does it have focus?

Comment: @jimmyLee well, thats not relevant to what im trying to do right now. I'm simply trying to scroll up and down the page. This code should be sufficient for a scroll, right?

Comment: @MadProgrammer im running this on my laptop, and yes, it has focus the entire time its running.

Comment: @user6561: Are you running it on IDE?

Comment: @Vishal yes on Eclipse

Comment: @user6561: Try my program and tell me if it is working fine for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program might not be working because either there is nothing to `scroll up` on the GUI to which your mouse pointer resting . Or, You have not rested your mouse pointer to the appropriate GUI on which you can see scroll effect. Here is the simple program to achieve that . I hope this would be of your help:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MouseScrollRobot extends JFrame
{

    JTextArea ta;
    boolean scrolledAway = false;
    Robot robot;
    boolean started = false;
    public void createAndShowGUI() 
    {
        setTitle("Robot Demonstration");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        ta = new JTextArea();   
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            robot = new Robot();
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MouseScrollRobot.java"));
            String line = null ;
            while ((line = bfr.readLine()) !=null)
            {
                sBuilder.append(line+"\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        ta.setText(sBuilder.toString());
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(ta);
        final Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                try
                {
                    robot.mouseMove((getLocationOnScreen().x + getWidth()) / 2 , (getLocationOnScreen().y + getHeight()) / 2);//Move mouse pointer to the Component which you want to scroll
                    ta.requestFocus();
                    robot.setAutoDelay(100);
                    if (!scrolledAway)
                    {
                        setTitle("Scrolling up");
                        robot.mouseWheel(-40);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        setTitle("Scrolling Down");
                        robot.mouseWheel(40);
                    }
                    scrolledAway = !scrolledAway;
                    setTitle("Scrolled");
                }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
        getContentPane().add(jsp);
        setSize(500,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            MouseScrollRobot msr = new MouseScrollRobot();
            msr.createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me...

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class TestRobotScroll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Robot bot = new Robot();
            bot.setAutoDelay(100);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("++");
            bot.mouseWheel(25);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("--");
            bot.mouseWheel(-25);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I had it scroll in the editor and scroll the browser...

Comment: see, same problem. It prints out ++ and --, but in between, nothing happens to the mouse! :'( I am writing an app for remote desktop control, and so far, I had mouse moves, taps, double taps, working perfectly with the robot class, but for some reason, mouseWHeel simply does nothing! Is there any alternative you can suggest?

Comment: I can't think of an alternative other then making sure the window that the mouse is over has focus. I got this to work while it ting over my IDE and Firefox window