# How to do smooth-scrolling by Java robot?

Tags: java, mousewheel, smooth-scrolling, awtrobot

I got used to my touch pad, that allows to scroll smoothly and very exactly, but I can not to simulate it by Java robot - mousewheel is getting only integer parameters and a scrolling carried by steps. Can I simulate smoothly scrolling in Java?

```
robot.mouseWheel(a); // int a
```

Comment: did you already tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714609/robot-class-mousewheel-not-working)?

Comment: @user6904265, It is not the same, scrolling works.
I want to scroll by px for example, not by big mousewheel steps.

Comment: @Антон theres now way to get around the units. Those notches are simply what any pointing-device provides. The rest is just OS-dependant. If you just want to scroll in a slower speed, that's pretty simple to implement though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit of scrolls will always be by "notches of the wheel" (before you ask: that's how the measurement is named in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseWheel(int))). This is simply how it's implemented by the hardware (to be more specific: the mouse). How many pixels are scrolled per "notch" is nothing but OS-configuration. You can't mess with that with pure java and I wouldn't recommend it, even if it was possible.

What you can do nevertheless is to slow down the speed at which the robot scrolls:

```
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        //time to switch to a specific window where the robot ought to be tested
        try{ Thread.sleep(2000); }catch(InterruptedException e){}

        Robot r = new Robot();
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            //scroll and wait a bit to give the impression of smooth scrolling
            r.mouseWheel(1);
            try{ Thread.sleep(50); }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my code looks like this example already... I thought there is some way to decrease step.